# How to remove validation from the "City" and "Street Address" Field on Customer Registration Page?

Tags: customer-account, magento-2.2.5, validation, form-validation

I've added **"Address Information"**  on customer registration page & want to remove the mandatory field from the **"City" and "Street Address" Field**  for that I've  overrided register.phtml file on my custom theme.

& When I clicked on **"Create An Account"** button then getting below **issue**:-

**"Delete operation is forbidden for current area"**

While in the backend created account is showing but "Telephone" field(this is mandatory) value is missing.

When I log in using created account uname & pswd it's working.

So why this issue is coming?how can i resolve it?if you've any alternate solution you can share.

**Please find the screenshots for the same:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**After debugging contrller **"Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost"** the problem is in below section:-**

[image]

Any update please?it's urgent so please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Here "city" is not mandatory so when i'm leaving this field(empty value) then getting this issue & when filling something then it's working fine.

Comment: The problem is in (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())). it seems that need  to work somwhere also.

Comment: Street address and City are not default fields in Customer Account Create form, How you add them ?

Comment: thanks for the reply,overrided customer_account_create.xml on my custom theme & added below code:- 

<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_address_fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: Even i tried to set static values like "NULL" on the controller "CreatePost.php" when "city" & "street address" fields are empty:-

 e.g-  if(empty($_POST['city'])) {$_POST['city']=NULL}

but it also doesn't work.

Comment: @wakarAhamad YOU SOLVED THIS ISSUE ?

Comment: Sorry,it didn't resolved yet.if you get something then please update here.